# opencv: Rigid Transformation between two 3D point clouds

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two 3D point clouds, and I'd like to use opencv to find the rigid transformation matrix (translation, rotation, constant scaling among all 3 axes).

I've found an [estimateRigidTransformation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=estimaterigidtransform#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine%29) function, but it's only for 2D points apparently

In addition, I've found [estimateAffine3D](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=estimate#cv2.estimateAffine3D), but it doesn't seem to support rigid transformation mode.

Do I need to just write my own rigid transformation function?

Comment: estimateAffine3D seems to do exactly what you want, no? Given two "clouds of points", that is anything but **exactly** 4 distinct points each, it is not possible to create a transform that is not an estimate. 4 distinct points define exactly 3 independent vectors. Fewer points leave the transform under-defined, more make it over-defined. This function does just what the name says, it returns the best estimate, i.e. something that more or less corresponds to the "average" of the transform the somewhat noisy points have undergone.

Comment: Thanks. I do want to estimate, but I'd like a rigid transformation, that is, without things like shearing. It doesn't seem to me that estimateAffine3D supports this, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Late, but don't know if this can help: http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671

Answer (score 4):

I did not find the required functionality in OpenCV so I have written my own implementation. Based on ideas from [OpenSFM](https://github.com/mapillary/OpenSfM/blob/61a98f6ab0f2d7b12592a92436648bd276f603d8/opensfm/transformations.py#L883).

```
cv::Vec3d
CalculateMean(const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3d> &points)
{
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3d> result;
    cv::reduce(points, result, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
    return result(0, 0);
}

cv::Mat_<double>
FindRigidTransform(const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3d> &points1, const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3d> points2)
{
    /* Calculate centroids. */
    cv::Vec3d t1 = -CalculateMean(points1);
    cv::Vec3d t2 = -CalculateMean(points2);

    cv::Mat_<double> T1 = cv::Mat_<double>::eye(4, 4);
    T1(0, 3) = t1[0];
    T1(1, 3) = t1[1];
    T1(2, 3) = t1[2];

    cv::Mat_<double> T2 = cv::Mat_<double>::eye(4, 4);
    T2(0, 3) = -t2[0];
    T2(1, 3) = -t2[1];
    T2(2, 3) = -t2[2];

    /* Calculate covariance matrix for input points. Also calculate RMS deviation from centroid
     * which is used for scale calculation.
     */
    cv::Mat_<double> C(3, 3, 0.0);
    double p1Rms = 0, p2Rms = 0;
    for (int ptIdx = 0; ptIdx < points1.rows; ptIdx++) {
        cv::Vec3d p1 = points1(ptIdx, 0) + t1;
        cv::Vec3d p2 = points2(ptIdx, 0) + t2;
        p1Rms += p1.dot(p1);
        p2Rms += p2.dot(p2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                C(i, j) += p2[i] * p1[j];
            }
        }
    }

    cv::Mat_<double> u, s, vh;
    cv::SVD::compute(C, s, u, vh);

    cv::Mat_<double> R = u * vh;

    if (cv::determinant(R) < 0) {
        R -= u.col(2) * (vh.row(2) * 2.0);
    }

    double scale = sqrt(p2Rms / p1Rms);
    R *= scale;

    cv::Mat_<double> M = cv::Mat_<double>::eye(4, 4);
    R.copyTo(M.colRange(0, 3).rowRange(0, 3));

    cv::Mat_<double> result = T2 * M * T1;
    result /= result(3, 3);

    return result.rowRange(0, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/about/) to be a nice adjunct to OpenCV.  Take a look at their [Iterative Closest Point (ICP) example](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php). The provided example registers the two point clouds and then displays the rigid transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rmsd code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct
{
  float m[4][4];
} MATRIX;

#define vdiff2(a,b) ( ((a)[0]-(b)[0]) * ((a)[0]-(b)[0]) +   \
  ((a)[1]-(b)[1]) * ((a)[1]-(b)[1]) + \
  ((a)[2]-(b)[2]) * ((a)[2]-(b)[2]) )

static double alignedrmsd(float *v1, float *v2, int N);
static void centroid(float *ret, float *v, int N);
static int getalignmtx(float *v1, float *v2, int N, MATRIX *mtx);
static void crossproduct(float *ans, float *pt1, float *pt2);
static void mtx_root(MATRIX *mtx);
static int almostequal(MATRIX *a, MATRIX *b);
static void mulpt(MATRIX *mtx, float *pt);
static void mtx_mul(MATRIX *ans, MATRIX *x, MATRIX *y);
static void mtx_identity(MATRIX *mtx);
static void mtx_trans(MATRIX *mtx, float x, float y, float z);
static int mtx_invert(float *mtx, int N);
static float absmaxv(float *v, int N);

/*
  calculate rmsd between two structures
  Params: v1 - first set of points
          v2 - second set of points
          N - number of points
          mtx - return for transfrom matrix used to align structures
  Returns: rmsd score
  Notes: mtx can be null. Transform will be rigid. Inputs must
         be previously aligned for sequence alignment
 */
double rmsd(float *v1, float *v2, int N, float *mtx)
{
  float cent1[3];
  float cent2[3];
  MATRIX tmtx;
  MATRIX tempmtx;
  MATRIX move1;
  MATRIX move2;
  int i;
  double answer;
  float *temp1 = 0;
  float *temp2 = 0;
  int err;

  assert(N > 3);

  temp1 = malloc(N * 3 * sizeof(float));
  temp2 = malloc(N * 3 * sizeof(float));
  if(!temp1 || !temp2)
    goto error_exit;

  centroid(cent1, v1, N);
  centroid(cent2, v2, N);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    temp1[i*3+0] = v1[i*3+0] - cent1[0];
    temp1[i*3+1] = v1[i*3+1] - cent1[1];
    temp1[i*3+2] = v1[i*3+2] - cent1[2];

    temp2[i*3+0] = v2[i*3+0] - cent2[0];
    temp2[i*3+1] = v2[i*3+1] - cent2[1];
    temp2[i*3+2] = v2[i*3+2] - cent2[2];
  }

  err = getalignmtx(temp1, temp2, N, &tmtx);
  if(err == -1)
    goto error_exit;

  mtx_trans(&move1, -cent2[0], -cent2[1], -cent2[2]);
  mtx_mul(&tempmtx, &move1, &tmtx);
  mtx_trans(&move2, cent1[0], cent1[1], cent1[2]);
  mtx_mul(&tmtx, &tempmtx, &move2);
  memcpy(temp2, v2, N * sizeof(float) * 3);
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    mulpt(&tmtx, temp2 + i * 3);
  answer = alignedrmsd(v1, temp2, N);
  free(temp1);
  free(temp2);
  if(mtx)
    memcpy(mtx, &tmtx.m, 16 * sizeof(float));

  return answer;
 error_exit:
  free(temp1);
  free(temp2);
  if(mtx)
  {
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
      mtx[i] = 0;
  }
  return sqrt(-1.0);
}

/*
  calculate rmsd between two aligned structures (trivial)
  Params: v1 - first structure
          v2 - second structure
          N - number of points
  Returns: rmsd
 */
static double alignedrmsd(float *v1, float *v2, int N)
{
  double answer =0;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    answer += vdiff2(v1 + i *3, v2 + i * 3);
  return sqrt(answer/N);
}

/*
  compute the centroid
 */
static void centroid(float *ret, float *v, int N)
{
  int i;

  ret[0] = 0;
  ret[1] = 0;
  ret[2] = 0;
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    ret[0] += v[i*3+0];
    ret[1] += v[i*3+1];
    ret[2] += v[i*3+2];
  }
  ret[0] /= N;
  ret[1] /= N;
  ret[2] /= N;
}

/*
  get the matrix needed to align two structures
  Params: v1 - reference structure
          v2 - structure to align
          N - number of points
          mtx - return for rigid body alignment matrix
  Notes: only calculates rotation part of matrix.
         assumes input has been aligned to centroids 
 */
static int getalignmtx(float *v1, float *v2, int N, MATRIX *mtx)
{
  MATRIX A = { {{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1}} };
  MATRIX At;
  MATRIX Ainv;
  MATRIX temp;
  float tv[3];
  float tw[3];
  float tv2[3];
  float tw2[3];
  int k, i, j;
  int flag = 0;
  float correction;

  correction = absmaxv(v1, N * 3) * absmaxv(v2, N * 3);

  for(k=0;k<N;k++)
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    A.m[i][j] += (v1[k*3+i] * v2[k*3+j])/correction;

  while(flag < 3)
  {
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        At.m[i][j] = A.m[j][i];

    memcpy(&Ainv, &A, sizeof(MATRIX));
    /* this will happen if all points are in a plane */
    if( mtx_invert((float *) &Ainv, 4) == -1)
    {
      if(flag == 0)
      {
        crossproduct(tv, v1, v1+3);
        crossproduct(tw, v2, v2+3);
      }
      else
      {
        crossproduct(tv2, tv, v1);
        crossproduct(tw2, tw, v2);
        memcpy(tv, tv2, 3 * sizeof(float));
        memcpy(tw, tw2, 3 * sizeof(float));
      }
      for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      A.m[i][j] += tv[i] * tw[j];

      flag++;
    }
    else
      flag = 5;
  }
  if(flag != 5)
    return -1;

  mtx_mul(&temp, &At, &A);
  mtx_root(&temp);
  mtx_mul(mtx, &temp, &Ainv); 
  return 0;
}

/*
  get the crossproduct of two vectors.
  Params: ans - return pinter for answer.
          pt1 - first vector
          pt2 - second vector.
  Notes: crossproduct is at right angles to the two vectors.
*/
static void crossproduct(float *ans, float *pt1, float *pt2)
{
  ans[0] = pt1[1] * pt2[2] - pt1[2] * pt2[1];
  ans[1] = pt1[0] * pt2[2] - pt1[2] * pt2[0];
  ans[2] = pt1[0] * pt2[1] - pt1[1] * pt2[0];
}

/*
  Denman-Beavers square root iteration
 */
static void mtx_root(MATRIX *mtx)
{
  MATRIX Y = *mtx;
  MATRIX Z;
  MATRIX Y1;
  MATRIX Z1;
  MATRIX invY;
  MATRIX invZ;
  MATRIX Y2;
  int iter = 0;
  int i, ii;

  mtx_identity(&Z);

  do
  {
    invY = Y;
    invZ = Z;
    if( mtx_invert((float *) &invY, 4) == -1)
      return;
    if( mtx_invert((float *) &invZ, 4) == -1)
      return;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
      {
        Y1.m[i][ii] = 0.5 * (Y.m[i][ii] + invZ.m[i][ii]);
    Z1.m[i][ii] = 0.5 * (Z.m[i][ii] + invY.m[i][ii]);
      }
    Y = Y1;
    Z = Z1;

    mtx_mul(&Y2, &Y, &Y);
  }
  while(!almostequal(&Y2, mtx) && iter++ < 20 );

  *mtx = Y;
}

/*
  Check two matrices for near-enough equality
  Params: a - first matrix
          b - second matrix
  Returns: 1 if almost equal, else 0, epsilon 0.0001f.
 */
static int almostequal(MATRIX *a, MATRIX *b)
{
  int i, ii;
  float epsilon = 0.001f;

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
      if(fabs(a->m[i][ii] - b->m[i][ii]) > epsilon) 
        return 0;
  return 1;
}  

/*
  multiply a point by a matrix.
  Params: mtx - matrix
          pt - the point (transformed)
*/
static void mulpt(MATRIX *mtx, float *pt)
{
  float ans[4] = {0};
  int i;
  int ii;

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    for(ii=0;ii<3;ii++)
    {
      ans[i] += pt[ii] * mtx->m[ii][i];
    }
    ans[i] += mtx->m[3][i];
  }
  pt[0] = ans[0];
  pt[1] = ans[1];
  pt[2] = ans[2];
} 

/*
  multiply two matrices.
  Params: ans - return pointer for answer.
          x - first matrix
          y - second matrix.
  Notes: ans may not be equal to x or y.
*/
static void mtx_mul(MATRIX *ans, MATRIX *x, MATRIX *y)
{
  int i;
  int ii;
  int iii;

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
    {
      ans->m[i][ii] = 0;
      for(iii=0;iii<4;iii++)
        ans->m[i][ii] += x->m[i][iii] * y->m[iii][ii];
    }
}


/*
  create an identity matrix.
  Params: mtx - return pointer.
*/
static void mtx_identity(MATRIX *mtx)
{
  int i;
  int ii;

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
    {
      if(i==ii)
        mtx->m[i][ii] = 1.0f;
      else
        mtx->m[i][ii] = 0;
    }
}

/*
  create a translation matrix.
  Params: mtx - return pointer for matrix.
          x - x translation.
          y - y translation.
          z - z translation
*/
static void mtx_trans(MATRIX *mtx, float x, float y, float z)
{
  mtx->m[0][0] = 1;
  mtx->m[0][1] = 0;
  mtx->m[0][2] = 0;
  mtx->m[0][3] = 0;

  mtx->m[1][0] = 0;
  mtx->m[1][1] = 1;
  mtx->m[1][2] = 0;
  mtx->m[1][3] = 0;

  mtx->m[2][0] = 0;
  mtx->m[2][1] = 0;
  mtx->m[2][2] = 1;
  mtx->m[2][3] = 0;

  mtx->m[3][0] = x;
  mtx->m[3][1] = y;
  mtx->m[3][2] = z;
  mtx->m[3][3] = 1; 
}

/*
   matrix invert routine
  Params: mtx - the matrix in raw format, in/out
          N - width and height
  Returns: 0 on success, -1 on fail
 */
static int mtx_invert(float *mtx, int N)
{
  int indxc[100]; /* these 100s are the only restriction on matrix size */
  int indxr[100];
  int ipiv[100];
  int i, j, k;
  int irow, icol;
  double big;
  double pinv;
  int l, ll;
  double dum;
  double temp;

  assert(N <= 100);

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    ipiv[i] = 0;

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    big = 0.0;

    /* find biggest element */
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
      if(ipiv[j] != 1)
        for(k=0;k<N;k++)
          if(ipiv[k] == 0)
            if(fabs(mtx[j*N+k]) >= big)
        {
           big = fabs(mtx[j*N+k]);
               irow = j;
               icol = k;
        }       

    ipiv[icol]=1;

    if(irow != icol)
      for(l=0;l<N;l++)
      {
        temp = mtx[irow * N + l];
        mtx[irow * N + l] = mtx[icol * N + l];
    mtx[icol * N + l] = temp;
      }

    indxr[i] = irow;
    indxc[i] = icol;


    /* if biggest element is zero matrix is singular, bail */
    if(mtx[icol* N + icol] == 0)
       goto error_exit;

    pinv = 1.0/mtx[icol * N + icol];

    mtx[icol * N + icol] = 1.0;

    for(l=0;l<N;l++)
      mtx[icol * N + l] *= pinv;

    for(ll=0;ll<N;ll++)
      if(ll != icol)
      {
        dum = mtx[ll * N + icol];
        mtx[ll * N + icol] = 0.0;
        for(l=0;l<N;l++) 
          mtx[ll * N + l] -= mtx[icol * N + l]*dum;
      }
  }                


  /* unscramble matrix */
  for (l=N-1;l>=0;l--) 
  {
    if (indxr[l] != indxc[l])
    for (k=0;k<N;k++)
    {
      temp = mtx[k * N + indxr[l]];
      mtx[k * N + indxr[l]] = mtx[k * N + indxc[l]];
      mtx[k * N + indxc[l]] = temp;
    }
  } 

  return 0;

 error_exit:
  return -1;
}

/*
  get the asolute maximum of an array
 */
static float absmaxv(float *v, int N)
{
  float answer;
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    if(answer < fabs(v[i]))
      answer = fabs(v[i]);
  return answer;
}

#include <stdio.h>

/*
  debug utlitiy
 */
static void printmtx(FILE *fp, MATRIX *mtx)
{
  int i, ii;

  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    for(ii=0;ii<4;ii++)
      fprintf(fp, "%f, ", mtx->m[i][ii]);
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
  }
}

int rmsdmain(void)
{
  float one[4*3] = {0,0,0, 1,0,0, 2,1,0, 0,3,1};
  float two[4*3] = {0,0,0, 0,1,0, 1,2,0, 3,0,1};
  MATRIX mtx;
  double diff;
  int i;

  diff = rmsd(one, two, 4, (float *) &mtx.m);
  printf("%f\n", diff);
  printmtx(stdout, &mtx);
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    mulpt(&mtx, two + i * 3);
    printf("%f %f %f\n", two[i*3], two[i*3+1], two[i*3+2]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @vagran's implementation and added RANSAC on top of it, since estimateRigidTransform2d does it and it was helpful for me since my data is noisy. (Note: This code doesn't have constant scaling along all 3 axes; you can add it back in easily by comparing to vargran's).

```
cv::Vec3f CalculateMean(const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> &points)
{
    if(points.size().height == 0){
      return 0;
    }
    assert(points.size().width == 1);
    double mx = 0.0;
    double my = 0.0;
    double mz = 0.0;
    int n_points = points.size().height;
    for(int i = 0; i < n_points; i++){
      double x = double(points(i)[0]);
      double y = double(points(i)[1]);
      double z = double(points(i)[2]);
      mx += x;
      my += y;
      mz += z;
    }
    return cv::Vec3f(mx/n_points, my/n_points, mz/n_points);
}

cv::Mat_<double>
FindRigidTransform(const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> &points1, const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> points2)
{
    /* Calculate centroids. */
    cv::Vec3f t1 = CalculateMean(points1);
    cv::Vec3f t2 = CalculateMean(points2);

    cv::Mat_<double> T1 = cv::Mat_<double>::eye(4, 4);
    T1(0, 3) = double(-t1[0]);
    T1(1, 3) = double(-t1[1]);
    T1(2, 3) = double(-t1[2]);

    cv::Mat_<double> T2 = cv::Mat_<double>::eye(4, 4);
    T2(0, 3) = double(t2[0]);
    T2(1, 3) = double(t2[1]);
    T2(2, 3) = double(t2[2]);

    /* Calculate covariance matrix for input points. Also calculate RMS deviation from centroid
     * which is used for scale calculation.
     */
    cv::Mat_<double> C(3, 3, 0.0);
    for (int ptIdx = 0; ptIdx < points1.rows; ptIdx++) {
        cv::Vec3f p1 = points1(ptIdx) - t1;
        cv::Vec3f p2 = points2(ptIdx) - t2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                C(i, j) += double(p2[i] * p1[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    cv::Mat_<double> u, s, vt;
    cv::SVD::compute(C, s, u, vt);

    cv::Mat_<double> R = u * vt;

    if (cv::determinant(R) < 0) {
        R -= u.col(2) * (vt.row(2) * 2.0);
    }

    cv::Mat_<double> M = cv::Mat_<double>::eye(4, 4);
    R.copyTo(M.colRange(0, 3).rowRange(0, 3));

    cv::Mat_<double> result = T2 * M * T1;
    result /= result(3, 3);
    return result;
}

cv::Mat_<double> RANSACFindRigidTransform(const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> &points1, const cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> &points2)
{
  cv::Mat points1Homo;
  cv::convertPointsToHomogeneous(points1, points1Homo);
  int iterations = 100;
  int min_n_points = 3;
  int n_points = points1.size().height;
  std::vector<int> range(n_points);
  cv::Mat_<double> best;
  int best_inliers = -1;
  // inlier points should be projected within this many units
  float threshold = .02;
  std::iota(range.begin(), range.end(), 0);
  auto gen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
  for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    std::shuffle(range.begin(), range.end(), gen);
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> points1subset(min_n_points, 1, cv::Vec3f(0,0,0));
    cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> points2subset(min_n_points, 1, cv::Vec3f(0,0,0));
    for(int j = 0; j < min_n_points; j++) {
      points1subset(j) = points1(range[j]);
      points2subset(j) = points2(range[j]);
    }
    cv::Mat_<float> rigidT = FindRigidTransform(points1subset, points2subset);
    cv::Mat_<float> rigidT_float = cv::Mat::eye(4, 4, CV_32F);
    rigidT.convertTo(rigidT_float, CV_32F);
    std::vector<int> inliers;
    for(int j = 0; j < n_points; j++) {
        cv::Mat_<float> t1_3d = rigidT_float * cv::Mat_<float>(points1Homo.at<cv::Vec4f>(j));
        if(t1_3d(3) == 0) {
          continue; // Avoid 0 division
        }
        float dx = (t1_3d(0)/t1_3d(3) - points2(j)[0]);
        float dy = (t1_3d(1)/t1_3d(3) - points2(j)[1]);
        float dz = (t1_3d(2)/t1_3d(3) - points2(j)[2]);
        float square_dist = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
        if(square_dist < threshold * threshold){
          inliers.push_back(j);
        }
    }
    int n_inliers = inliers.size();
    if(n_inliers > best_inliers) {
      best_inliers = n_inliers;
      best = rigidT;
    }
  }
  return best;
}
```

Comment: This is the same implementation principle as the MATLAB built-in function [estrigidtform3d](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/vision/ref/estgeotform3d.html), SVD+RANSAC combined

Answer (score 0):

@vagran Thanks for the code! Seems to work very well.

I do have a little terminology suggestion though. Since you are estimating and applying a scale during the transformation, it is a 7-parameter transformation, or Helmert / similarity transformation. And in a rigid transformation, no scaling is applied because all Euclidiean distances need to be reserved.

I would've added this as comment, but don't have enough points.. D: sorry for that.

- rigid transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation
- Helmert transformation: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322841143_Parameter_estimation_in_3D_affine_and_similarity_transformation_implementation_of_variance_component_estimation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31673848)